# How to sum amount with a criteria separately by day in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-timestamp

I am using Google Sheets to track income and expenses. I have a separate file for each month and a master file to summarize each month.

The file for monthly account contains a couple of sheets - each separate sheet including income from carrying out a service, income from selling a product, expenses and such.

Services sheet looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to be able to sum up the income from each such sheet by date. The easiest and the only way I know how to do so is by using **=SUMIF** formula to sum amounts from "C" column by inputting a whole date from column "A" as a criteria, like so:

```
=SUMIF(inservice!A3:A200;"2019-09-03";inservice!C3:C200)
```

It does the job but the thing is each month I would have to change the date (month and year specifically) in the formula manually and that's a thing I would like to avoid.
I have tried going around this problem with changing the formula to:

```
=SUMIF(inservice!A3:A200;"*03";inservice!C3:C200)
```

I have though that by doing so it would only sum amount from the "C" column if date in the "A" column ended with a specific day - in this case it being "03", however the sum is always "0", therefore this solution does not work for me.

Is there a way to go around this problem by using the **=SUMIF** modified formula?

Another solution I was thinking of is to input all dates in separate cells and use each cell as a criteria for **=SUMIF** formula but for this to work I would need a formula that automatically changes month and year accordingly in these reference dates, unless such formula can be placed within **=SUMIF** itself.

I have a feeling it's a very roundabout way to achieve what I am trying to do, but in any case I hope an example of what I mean will help - let's say that the forth column in the picture below is called "D" and I use it as a range for a criteria to be met in the formula. In order to calculate amount earned on 2019-09-03 I would use such formula (where D192 equals *2019-09-03*):

`=SUMIF(inservice!A3:A200;inservice!D192;inservice!C3:C200)`

[image]

But again - for this to work I would need to find a way for dates in "D" column to change with each new file automatically as it is very bothersome to redo it every single month.

I hope I have explained everything comprehensibly. I do have a feeling an array formula may be a solution sought, however every time I have tried to include it while using Google Sheets it does not give me desired results and I fear I do not have a good understanding of how it works.

I have started learning formulas since a couple of months ago when it became apparent I have needed more orderly calculated account, therefore treat me as a total beginner and please do try to make your explanations as simple as possible.

Comment: What about `=SUMIF(inservice!A3:A200;$E$1;inservice!C3:C200)` where `E1` is the date you need ? (I.E. `2019-09-03` here). You''ll have only 1 cell to modify each month. (and btw you can us `CTRL + D` to expand formulas) If you can provide a sample with your problem and desired result too, it'll be a way for us to better understand your problem.

Answer (score -1):

This formula sums all the sums in column C by date:

```
=sort(transpose(QUERY(inservice!A3:C200, "select SUM(C) where A is not null pivot A", 0)), 1, FALSE)
```

Result:

[image: Result given your example]

You might want to check the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function, which is what solves your problem. I used [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) and [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) in order to keep your presentation style.

Comment: Please briefly describe how this answer the question.